# Correctly removing fragment when finished

Tags: android, android-fragments

When switching between multiple fragments is it necessary to start a new `FragmentTransaction` and remove each fragment when finished or, for example, if references to the fragments are stored as instance variables (to provide access to fragment methods from the host activity) is setting the instance variables to null when the fragment is replaced sufficient?

I am concerned if each fragment is not removed that it somehow lives on at least until a new fragment with the same id is added to replace the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the fragment is replaced with another fragment it will call the `onDestroy` method of the replaced fragment.

```
is setting the instance variables to null when the fragment is replaced sufficient?
```

There is nothing already in there when you replace the fragment and when you call it, let say a `getter method` it will return `null`  because `onDestroy` already clean out all the data that was inside of that fragment.